# Search for and move references to inline occurrence

Tags: python, perl, awk, sed, replace

I'm exporting a Google Docs and convert it with https://github.com/facundoolano/googledoc2latex. (It's the most accurate and free tool I've found so far).

Footnotes from Docs are (as in the html version) below the text.

```
[text]
This is an example.$^{[1]}$ I like it.$^{[2]}$
[text]
[1] I'm a footnote!
[2] I'm also a footnote!
```

The expected result should be

```
[text]
This is an example.\footnote{I'm a footnote!} I like it.\footnote{I'm also a footnote!}
[text]
```

For my purpose, it could be done with awk, sed, perl, python, bash... For the long run, python would be awesome since it could be merged to the project.

So the script needs to find all references and replace them with the real text.

I did not find a way to start with sed and awk and are not experienced with perl and python. Any suggestions?

Comment: Python comes with a regular expression module named [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) which can do that.

Answer (score 3):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne '
    if (/^(\[[0-9]+\]) (.*)/) {
        $f{$1} = $2;
    } else { 
        push @lines, $_;
    }
    END {
        print s{\$\^\{(\[[0-9]+\])\}\$}{$f{$1} // "Missing $1!!!"}ger
            for @lines }
' -- file.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- The first regex matches the definition of a footnote, it stores the text into the hash `%f` under the key `[1]`, `[2]` etc.
- Lines not containing a footnote definition are stored in the `@lines` array
- Once the file has been read, the stored lines are printed. On each line, the references to footnotes are replaced by the values stored in the hash, or by a `Missing [4]` if the definition is not found.

Answer (score 3):

Perl code algorithm

- separate text from footnotes with regular expression
- make replacement for each footnote

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $text;
my %footnote;

/^\[(\d+)\] (.*)\Z/ ? $footnote{$1} = $2 : ($text .= $_) while <DATA>;

$text =~ s/\$\^\{\[$_\]\}\$/\\footnote{$footnote{$_}}/g for keys %footnote;

say $text;

__DATA__
[text]
This is an example.$^{[1]}$ I like it.$^{[2]}$
[text]
[1] I'm a footnote!
[2] I'm also a footnote!
```

Output

```
[text]
This is an example.\footnote{I'm a footnote!} I like it.\footnote{I'm also a footnote!}
[text]
```